# Creating several tables from CSV with PHP

Tags: php, html-table, import-from-csv

The following code works with the CSV-file.

But I want to create more than one table and the values are in the same CSV.

How should I use the `$rowcount` in the second table, that should look like the first one, only with other first-value for th and the following values for the td's.

```
<a name="akademische-berufe"></a> 
<table class="table-vocabulary">
<tbody>   
<?php 
$file = new SplFileObject("arbeit.csv");
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

$rowcount = 0;
foreach ($file as $row) {
  $rowcount++;
  if ($rowcount == 1) {
  list($vokabel_en, $vokabel_de) = $row;      
    printf('
    <tr>
      <th><img src="/bilder/symbole/play.png" data-text="%1$s" data-lang="'.$lang_code1.'" class="trigger_play"> %1$s</th> 
      <th><img src="/bilder/symbole/play.png" data-text="%2$s" data-lang="'.$lang_code2.'" class="trigger_play"> %2$s</th>
    </tr>', $vokabel_en, $vokabel_de);
    continue;
}  
  if ($rowcount >= 31) break;
  list($vokabel_en, $vokabel_de) = $row;      
    printf('
    <tr>
      <td><img src="/bilder/symbole/play.png" data-text="%1$s" data-lang="'.$lang_code1.'" class="trigger_play"> %1$s</td> 
      <td><img src="/bilder/symbole/play.png" data-text="%2$s" data-lang="'.$lang_code2.'" class="trigger_play"> %2$s</td>
    </tr>', $vokabel_en, $vokabel_de); 
}  
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a function with the parameters you want. Let the function also echo (print) the table tag and you are done.

User-defined php functions:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

The code could then look like this:

```
<a name="akademische-berufe"></a>  
<?php
function CreateLangTable($csvFile, $startRow, $endRow) {
  if ($endRow < $startRow) {
    return;
  }

  echo '<table class="table-vocabulary"><tbody>';

  $csvFile->seek($startRow);

  vprintf('
      <tr>
        <th><img src="/bilder/symbole/play.png" data-text="%1$s" data-lang="'.$lang_code1.'" class="trigger_play"> %1$s</th> 
        <th><img src="/bilder/symbole/play.png" data-text="%2$s" data-lang="'.$lang_code2.'" class="trigger_play"> %2$s</th>
      </tr>', 
      $csvFile->current());

  while ($csvFile->key() <= $endRow) {
    $csvFile->next();

    vprintf('
      <tr>
        <td><img src="/bilder/symbole/play.png" data-text="%1$s" data-lang="'.$lang_code1.'" class="trigger_play"> %1$s</td> 
        <td><img src="/bilder/symbole/play.png" data-text="%2$s" data-lang="'.$lang_code2.'" class="trigger_play"> %2$s</td>
      </tr>', 
      $csvFile->current());
  }

  echo '</tbody></table>';
}

$file = new SplFileObject("arbeit.csv");
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

CreateLangTable($file, 1, 31);

CreateLangTable($file, 33, 58);
?>
```

**EDIT:** In case you have empty rows dividing the tables then instead of

```
while ($csvFile->key() <= $endRow)
```

you can use

```
while (!empty($csvFile->current()))
```

you can then obviously omit/remove the function parameter $endRow

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how? Can you show me it?

Comment: Ok, no problem. Give me few minutes.

Comment: How exactly would you like to change the values in th and td? What should change there?

Comment: first table th 1 td's 2-31, second table th  33, td's  34-58

Comment: Yes, well list is a pretty old construction that should not be used at all in php in my opinion. And since you use the SplFileObject, maybe it would be wise to do the whole thing in an object...but the function will do fine as well. There are some basic design mistakes in the code though, but you will learn that in time and practise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57089/discussion-between-santhos-and-grischa).

Comment: Thank you very much for your edit. I searching for hours, how this should work and created a new question [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703373/) here for it. But I need a model version for several sites with different numbers for tables to create, that's why  I have to odmit also the parameter `$startRow` to create tables with one line like `CreateLangTable($file);`

Comment: I don't understand, why you edited the answer with a solution for my a part of my question, if you think my question is to stupid or something like that for stackoverview.